# Adding a background-image using the Parallax effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I’m in the process of adding the parallax effect to the background of my “contact page”. Unfortunately, my Css style-sheet is not responding to the background-image placed so I decided to test the background-color and sure enough my background is a different color but how do I replace that color with and image?

```
<!--html-->
 <div class="container" id="contact"><!--container-fluid 2 begins-->
  <div class=" address column2">
   <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Address:</h1>
    <p> 292250 Ace Center Dr. 1022</p>
    <p> Houston, Texas 77518 </p>
 </div>
  <div class="email column2">
   <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Email:</h2>
    <p>broo@gmail.com</p>
 </div>
 <div class="phonenumber column2">
   <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span> Phone Number:  </h2>
    <p>1(832)555-9209</p>
  </div>
  <div class="social column2">
   <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Social Connection</h2> 
     <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.facebook.com/brooks.7739"                      role="button">Facebook &raquo;</a>
   <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/brooks-  mmis/5b/97/7a4" role="button">LinkedIn &raquo;</a></p>
 </div> 
  </div><!--container-fluid"2 ends-->


<!--CSS-->
 #contact{
background-image: url("img/contact.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #dddddd;
color: white;
padding:100px;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 600px;
z-index: 1;
}

<!--JS-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $root = $('html, body');
      $('.navbar-nav a').click(function() {
          var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
          $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
          }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
          });
          return false;
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your CSS is completely fine, there must be something wrong with the path to the image.

Comment: <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!--latest compiled and minifield css--> 
        <link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: The link seems to be working fine with the style-sheet. I'm going to try a few tricks with the image it's self.

Comment: What does bootstrap have to do with this though?

Comment: It's for something different.... avoid that part.

Comment: I found the problem...... It was a problem with that particular img.... thanks